# Immutable.js update deeply nested Map

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

I'm having trouble updating a redux store. I have tabular data in store and the update patch comes in with selection and the value to be updated. The state of the store looks like this:

```
const state = fromJS({
  data: {
    rows: {
      row1: {
        col1: { amount: 1 },
        col2: { amount: 1 },
        col3: { amount: 1 },
        col4: { amount: 1 },
      },
      row2: {
        col1: { amount: 2 },
        col2: { amount: 2 },
        col3: { amount: 2 },
        col4: { amount: 2 },
      },
      row3: {
        col1: { amount: 3 },
        col2: { amount: 3 },
        col3: { amount: 3 },
        col4: { amount: 3 },
      },
      row4: {
        col1: { amount: 4 },
        col2: { amount: 4 },
        col3: { amount: 4 },
        col4: { amount: 4 },
      },
    }
  }
});

const newAmount = 5;

const selection = [
  { row: 'row1', column: 'col1' },
  { row: 'row1', column: 'col2' },
  { row: 'row2', column: 'col1' },
  { row: 'row2', column: 'col2' },
];
```

Selection can be only one cell or multiple cells on one or more rows. Each cell should be updated with the same value. What is the proper way to update the store so that the next state would look like this.

```
const nextState = fromJS({
  data: {
    rows: {
      row1: {
        col1: { amount: 5 }, // updated with newAmount 
        col2: { amount: 5 }, // updated with newAmount
        col3: { amount: 1 },
        col4: { amount: 1 },
      },
      row2: {
        col1: { amount: 5 }, // updated with newAmount
        col2: { amount: 5 }, // updated with newAmount
        col3: { amount: 2 },
        col4: { amount: 2 },
      },
      row3: {
        col1: { amount: 3 },
        col2: { amount: 3 },
        col3: { amount: 3 },
        col4: { amount: 3 },
      },
      row4: {
        col1: { amount: 4 },
        col2: { amount: 4 },
        col3: { amount: 4 },
        col4: { amount: 4 },
      },
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know Immutable.js but when you are dealing with object immutability core object does not change and new object is given to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (code-wise) I could find is:

```
const newState = state.withMutations(newStore => {
  selection.forEach((selection) => {
    newStore.setIn(['data', 'rows', selection.row, selection.column, 'amount'], newAmount)
  }) 
})
```

The benefit of this approach is that you just iterate what is going to change. I don't think it's worth to do it without `withMutation` because the code may look quite hard to deal with.

Comment: Another valid approach would be mimicking the state object with just the changes and performing a mergeDeep.

Comment: This was my initial approach but I never got it working. Your solution is great. Thanks!